# Can I draw an image into a Canvas?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a function that draws a Shape into a Sprite. I want to change the function to use an Image instead of a Shape, but the image will not show. What can I do to make the image show? lineChartContainer is the Sprite.

```
function drawCircle(x:Number,y:Number):void{
                //var circle:Shape = new Shape();
                circle.graphics.beginFill(0xf1e500, 1);
                var lineThickness:int = 6;
                circle.graphics.drawCircle(x + (0), y - (0), lineThickness);
                circle.graphics.endFill();
                lineChartContainer.addChild(circle);
                var graphic:Image = new Image();
                graphic.source="images/grade.png";
                lineChartContainer.addChild(graphic);
            }
```

Comment: You have not shown code that will size [or place] your Image component.  You may benefit from reviewing the Flex Component Lifecycle. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ascomponents_advanced_2.html

Comment: I don't think there's necessarily anything wrong with your code, the Image itself should calculate it's size when the source finishes loading (asynchronously), the position would just be 0,0 by default which may put it offscreen depending on where the parent is located in the global coordinate space.  Otherwise just verify that the source path includes the directory that includes "images/grade.png" perhaps try with an absolute URL like http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png to be sure it's not a path issue.

Comment: shaunhusain thanks for your reply. I tried the absolute url, but nothing shows up yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do will never work.

The variable `lineChartContainer` is a Sprite.

Flex components (like the `Image` control) cannot be parented by non-Flex components.  So while it's perfectly legal AS3 code to do:

```
lineChartContainer.addChild(graphic)
```

The Flex component won't render anything.  Flex components have a "life cycle" and the component needs to go through an iteration of the life cycle before it will actually render something. But since the `Image` control is being added to a `Sprite` the life cycle for the `Image` component never starts.

You mention a `Canvas` in the title of your question. Try adding the `Image` component to a `Canvas`, `VBox`, `HBox`, `Group`, `VGroup`, `HGroup`, or some other Flex container class.